# Inserting millions of rows in an SQLite database, Python is too slow

Tags: python, sqlite, chess

For my chess engine I use statistics to choose optimal moves. I collected them from millions of games. I'm interested in the **current move**, the **next move** and how much times the **next move** was played given the **current move**.

For using a Python dictionary and storing it with pickle the file is too large, and hard to update with new games. So I decided to use SQLite.

I created a class `MovesDatabase`:

```
class MovesDatabase:

def __init__(self, work_dir):
    self.con = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(work_dir, "moves.db"))
    self.con.execute('PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY')
    self.con.execute('PRAGMA synchronous = NORMAL')
    self.con.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL')
    self.cur = self.con.cursor()

    self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS moves("
                     "move TEXT,"
                     "next TEXT,"
                     "count INTEGER DEFAULT 1);")
```

`move` and `next` represent the state of a chess board in a string format: FEN. Example:

- rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR
- r1b1k1nr/p2p1pNp/n2B4/1p1NP2P/6P1/3P1Q2/P1P1K3/q5b1
- 8/8/8/4p1K1/2k1P3/8/8/8 b

The method below is responsible for taking a games file, extracting the moves and inserting if the couple (`move`, `next`) is new, or updating if (`move`, `next`) already exist in the database:

```
def insert_moves_from_file(self, file: str):
    print("Extracting moves to database from " + file)

    count = 0

    with open(file) as games_file:
        game = chess.pgn.read_game(games_file)

        while game is not None:
            batch = []
            board = game.board()
            state_one = board.fen().split(' ')[0] + ' ' + board.fen().split(' ')[1]

            for move in game.mainline_moves():
                board.push(move)
                fen = board.fen().split(' ')
                state_two = fen[0] + ' ' + fen[1]

                res = self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM moves WHERE move=? AND next=?",
                                       (state_one, state_two))
                res = res.fetchall()

                if len(res) != 0:
                    self.cur.execute("UPDATE moves SET count=count+1 WHERE move=? AND next=?",
                                     (state_one, state_two))
                else:
                    batch.append((state_one, state_two))

                state_one = state_two

            self.cur.executemany("INSERT INTO moves(move, next) VALUES"
                                 "(?, ?)", batch)
            count += 1
            print('\r' "%d games was add to the database.." % (count + 1), end='')
            game = chess.pgn.read_game(games_file)

    self.con.commit()
    print("\n Finished!")
```

The couple (`move`, `next`) is unique.

I tested with a file containing approximately 4 million (`move`, `next`). It started inserting/updating 3.000 rows/s, but with 50K rows it slows down to 100 rows/s and keeps going down. I designed this method to process multiple game files, that's why I choose an SQL database in the first place.

Comment: 3K rows/s is not really good. Are you planning to use this script once, or are you developing a tool for regular use?

Comment: I suppose, `count` should be named more like `move_number`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not `INSERT`ing that's slow here.

Your `move` and `next` columns aren't indexed, so any `SELECT` or `UPDATE` involving those columns requires a full table scan.

If `(move, next)` is always unique, you'll want to add an `UNIQUE` index on that. It will also automagically make the queries that query for `move`/`next` pairs faster (but not necessarily those that query for only one of those two columns).

To create that index on your existing table,

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_move_next ON moves (move, next);
```

Finally, once you have that index in place, you can get rid of the whole `SELECT`/`UPDATE` thing too with an upsert:

```
INSERT INTO moves (move, next) VALUES (?, ?) ON CONFLICT (move, next) DO UPDATE SET count = count + 1;
```

---

Here's a slight refactoring that achieves about 6200 moves/second inserted on my machine. (It requires the `tqdm` library for a nice progress bar, and a `pgns/` directory with PGN files.)

```
import glob
import sqlite3
import chess.pgn
import tqdm
from chess import WHITE


def board_to_state(board):
    # These were extracted from the implementation of `board.fen()`
    # so as to avoid doing extra work we don't need.
    bfen = board.board_fen(promoted=False)
    turn = ("w" if board.turn == WHITE else "b")
    return f'{bfen} {turn}'


def insert_game(cur, game):
    batch = []
    board = game.board()
    state_one = board_to_state(board)
    for move in game.mainline_moves():
        board.push(move)
        state_two = board_to_state(board)
        batch.append((state_one, state_two))
        state_one = state_two
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO moves (move, next) VALUES (?, ?) ON CONFLICT (move, next) DO UPDATE SET count = count + 1", batch)
    n_moves = len(batch)
    return n_moves


def main():
    con = sqlite3.connect("moves.db")
    con.execute('PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY')
    con.execute('PRAGMA synchronous = NORMAL')
    con.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL')
    con.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS moves(move TEXT,next TEXT,count INTEGER DEFAULT 1);')
    con.execute('CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ix_move_next ON moves (move, next);')

    cur = con.cursor()

    for pgn_file in sorted(glob.glob("pgns/*.pgn")):
        with open(pgn_file) as games_file:
            n_games = 0
            with tqdm.tqdm(desc=pgn_file, unit="moves") as pbar:
                while (game := chess.pgn.read_game(games_file)):
                    n_moves = insert_game(cur, game)
                    n_games += 1
                    pbar.set_description(f"{pgn_file} ({n_games} games)", refresh=False)
                    pbar.update(n_moves)
            con.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is perfect. Although, do you know any PRAGMA that could improve the inserting/updating rate without corrupting the data?

Comment: If you're just doing initial population, I'd just YOLO and turn all safety off for that time. You won't have multiple readers or multiple writers at that time, and if something is corrupted, you can retry.

Comment: By the way, you could eke out even more performance by not calling `board.fen().split()` twice... :)

Comment: And in case I adding data to an already populated database?

Comment: Well, considering SQLite databases are stored in a single file, you could always copy the database into a temporary place, do unsafe updates on the copy, and if everything is fine, replace the original with the updated copy... :)

Comment: Haha, that's one is called one time. Inside the loop I actually store the value.

Comment: @LukeWardford You're welcome! I edited a refactored example into the answer; I got a nice increase of about 200moves/sec by not having to split/rejoin the `.fen()` string, but by instead calling the functions it calls. :)

Comment: ... furthermore, running a profiler on this, it looks like a couple of tweaks to the internals of the `chess` module (namely that `Piece`s are immutable and can thus be cached) gives me 7000moves/sec... anyway, I think I had actual work to do too.